# AWS Elasticsearch - Query Cache

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I am using AWS Elasticsearch and the cluster receives ~ 600 search queries per second. This is causing periodic bursts of 503 Service not available response from Elasticsearch. As, a result I wanted to turn on the cache query for the index (Verified that is it actually turned on by looking at `<ES_DOMAIN>/<INDEX_NAME>`

However, when I check the query cache stats at `<ES_DOMAIN>/_stats/query_cache?pretty&human`, this is what I get

```
"<index_name>" : {
      "primaries" : {
        "query_cache" : {
          "memory_size" : "0b",
          "memory_size_in_bytes" : 0,
          "evictions" : 0,
          "hit_count" : 0,
          "miss_count" : 0
        }
      },
      "total" : {
        "query_cache" : {
          "memory_size" : "0b",
          "memory_size_in_bytes" : 0,
          "evictions" : 0,
          "hit_count" : 0,
          "miss_count" : 0
        }
      }
    }
```

Any suggestions on how I can turn on the cache ?

Comment: Can you show the kind of queries you're running? It is worth noting that only queries in the context of filters will be cached, not normal queries.

Comment: Could you try to specify url cache parameter per request and compare results: &query_cache=true

Comment: Could you make sure, that queries get serialized in the same way? Elasticsearch uses entire json body as cache key.

Answer (score 3):

Based on my [reading](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.5/index-modules-shard-query-cache.html) and similar experience (even after setting `index.cache.query.enable: true` in the index mapping) I can only guess that AWS has disabled query caching. Probably by setting `indices.cache.query.size: 0%` in `config/elasticsearch.yml`

**UPDATE**

After leaving the cluster running for a while and doing some heavy aggregations I am seeing that the `query_cache` is starting to get used, although not sure why I am not seeing any `cache hits`

`GET _nodes/stats/indices/query_cache?pretty&human`

```
{
   "cluster_name": "XXXXXXXXXXXX:xxxxxxxxxxx",
   "nodes": {
      "q59YfHDdRQupousO9vh6KQ": {
         "timestamp": 1465589579698,
         "name": "Mongoose",
         "indices": {
            "query_cache": {
               "memory_size": "37.2kb",
               "memory_size_in_bytes": 38151,
               "evictions": 0,
               "hit_count": 0,
               "miss_count": 45
            }
         }
      },
      "K3olMnkkRZW53tTw05UVhA": {
         "timestamp": 1465589579692,
         "name": "Meggan Braddock",
         "indices": {
            "query_cache": {
               "memory_size": "47.3kb",
               "memory_size_in_bytes": 48497,
               "evictions": 0,
               "hit_count": 0,
               "miss_count": 53
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```